# Android - How to set bottom padding for Google Logo on Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In iOS, this is pretty easy.

In Android though, I've tried adding padding to the bottom of the map both through xml as in `android:paddingBottom=80dp"` as well as programmatically as in `mapView.setPadding(0,0,0,80)`. In both cases, the map moves up as well as if it got cut and a blank space appears where actually only the Google logo should have moved up while the map should have remained with full height.

Here's my xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

So, the mapView continues with full height but the Google Maps' map moves up because of the padding. Is there a way to move up only the Google logo while the Google Maps' map stays intact?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MapView is just a FrameLayout container for the map. Instead, add the padding to the GoogleMap Object in your onMapReady callback. Like so:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
         map.setPadding(0,0,0,80);
}
```

Also remember the values for paddings here are in pixels, you can use this function to do the conversion:

```
 public static int dpToPx(int dp, Context context) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
 }


public static void setPaddingForGoogleLogo(GoogleMap map, Context context) {
    map.setPadding(LayoutUtils.dpToPx(15, context),
            LayoutUtils.dpToPx(45, context),
            LayoutUtils.dpToPx(0, context),
            LayoutUtils.dpToPx(85, context));
}
```

The values above worked in my case, that is similar to yours but probably you need to do some tests